Web scraping dropdown menu
I want to get the list of each make and model from the following website. So far, I have the following. It gives me the mark correctly, but not the model. I think the problem is that the code does not select the make correctly for the model to have options through the drop-down.
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))

driver.get("https://www.nettiauto.com/")

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
merkki_dropdown = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//select[@name="make"]')))

select_merkki = Select(merkki_dropdown)

for merkki_option in select_merkki.options:
    merkki_name = merkki_option.text.strip()

    if merkki_name == "" or "Select" in merkki_name:
        continue

    select_merkki.select_by_visible_text(merkki_name)

    model_dropdown = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//select[@name="model"]')))

    model_options = model_dropdown.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "option")

    model_list = [option.text.strip() for option in model_options if option.text.strip()]

    print(f'Make: {merkki_name}')
    for model in model_list:
        print(f'  Model: {model}')

driver.quit()


This is the way to get the options out of <select>:
select_model = Select(model_dropdown)
model_list = [option.text.strip() for option in select_model.options if option.text.strip()]

if needed, use WebDriverWait explicitly wait for the model options to update

This does not seem to work.

@Mansoor, what is the error?

There is no error. The output prints the Make and then "Model: Malli" for each Make just like it did before.

use import pdb;pdb.set_trace() and you will have interactive shell at that line. So, you can see locally what is happening. If your codes works fine in the interactive shell, then it is a timing issue.

Thank you for this. The issue seems to be that even if a specific Make is selected, the option for Malli (Model) is still grey.
